# Creating a text animated video using Python

Tags: python, audio, text-to-speech, data-extraction

I want to create a text animated video using Python, similar to a google slide presentation, however, I am developing a generic video creating model that makes a presentation video with simple fade in animated texts based on user data so I cannot manually create a presentation for each user, the process needs to be automated. Moreover, is there a TTS module in python except pyttx3 that can produce natural audio based on the text provided. Due to certain constraints I cannot use APIs.

Finally, I want to combine the audio and video in sync. How can I execute the entire procedure in Python and which modules shall I use to get the most appropriate output?

I have explored pyttx3 and gtts for TTS, but they create an extremely robotic voice output. Furthermore, I thought about using tkinter to animate the text or create a powerpoint presentation using the pptx python module that will create a presentation based on the input provided and then use pptx2mp4 to convert it into a video. Is there a better solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try https://github.com/neonbjb/tortoise-tts

It takes a lot of time to render if done on CPU. If using on CPU i'd recommend lowering the preset to fast.

You'll be able to render literally any voice. Even your own.

And the output is very natural.

Here is a sample

https://drive.google.com/file/d/11WqZq4ogDWX8UHnlhduMQSlFsFSqryrd/view?usp=share_link

Another option is to use https://huggingface.co/espnet/kan-bayashi_ljspeech_vits